# How to Do Interface-driven Write with Realm when Datasource is Results Object

Tags: swift, realm

The Realm documentation for an [interface-driven write](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#interface-driven-writes) indicates that you can add a record to a collection like this:

```
func insertItem() throws {
  // Perform an interface-driven write on the main thread:
  collection.realm!.beginWrite()
  collection.insert(Item(), at: 0)
  // And mirror it instantly in the UI
  tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
  // Making sure the change notification doesn't apply the change a second time
  try collection.realm!.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [token])
}
```

This seems to imply that the datasource for the table is an `Array` because there is not an `insert` method on a `Results<Item>` collection.

What data type is `collection` in this situation? It seems like it's an array, but my understanding is that you can't create a Realm notification on an array.

I've also read that it's **not a good idea** to copy all your Realm objects into an array (for performance reasons) since the results are accessed lazily. But it would seem that interface-driven writes are impossible unless you do.

Any suggestions on how to properly set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is a bit vague but the specific answer to your question is that in this case, collection is a List type. See the documentation for [Collections](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collections).

To drill down a bit, here's an example implementation.

Suppose we have a Person Object and each person has a List property of Dog Objects.

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var person_name = ""
    let dogs = List<DogClass>()
}

class DogClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var dog_name = ""
    @objc dynamic var dog_age = 0
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: PersonClass.self, property: "dogs")
}
```

We want to know when a specific person gets a new dog, update our tableView with that dog info immediately and not receive a Realm notification for the event.

Here's the code to set up an observer for Jean-Luc's dogs.

```
//a class var for the notification and the List.
var dogListNotificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil
var dogList: List<DogClass>? = nil

func doObserveDogList() {
    if let realm = gGetRealm() { //using a singleton Realm for this example
        let personResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter("name == 'Jean-Luc'")
        let firstPerson = personResults.first
        self.dogList = firstPerson?.dogs
    }

    if self.dogList == nil {
        print("there were no dogs for this person")
        return
    }

    self.dogListNotificationToken = self.dogList!.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        switch changes {
        case .initial:
            print("initial object load complete")
            if let results = self.dogList {
                for d in results {
                    print(d.dog_name, d.dog_age)
                }
            }
            break

        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            print(" handle item delete, insert or mod")

            for index in deletions {
                print("  deleted object at index: \(index)")
            }

            for index in insertions {
                print("  inserted object at index: \(index)")
            }

            for index in modifications {
                print("  modified object at index: \(index)")
            }

            break

        case .error(let error):
            // An error occurred
            fatalError("\(error)")
            break

        }
    }
}
```

and suppose Jean-Luc get gets a new dog so we need to insert that into realm but don't want a notification because we want to handle it 'immediately'.

```
func insertDog() {
    let dogToAdd = DogClass()
    dogToAdd.dog_name = "Number 1"
    dogToAdd.dog_age = 5
    self.dogList?.realm?.beginWrite()
    self.dogList?.insert(dogToAdd, at: 0)
    //insert into tableView/datasource/whatever
    try! self.dogList?.realm!.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [self.dogListNotificationToken!])
}
```

The above will result in the Dog 'Number 1' being added to Jean-Luc's dog list with no observe event being triggered upon the insert.